# Execute Mysql queries using the same file more than once

Tags: mysql

I have a file with .sql extension in which I write a query like insertions, deletions or updates, and execute it in toadformysql . I repeat the same action many times because I have lot of queries, so it turned out that I have a lot .sql files. 
for the first query  It works . but When I tried to add a second query in the same file and execute it  , there are  errors because the first query has already been executed. If the first query is delete for example, it displays an error "no such column" , which is logic beacuse I already delete the column.
Is there a way that I can have a single file in which I add all my queries and while executing it , I won't have errors from old queries like duplicates or others, something like errors handling. It is because I have to keep an history of all queries.
Only the query that I didn't already execute will throw an error if there is.

for example if my first query is

```
ALTER TABLE adbproject DROP COLUMN imageFormat
```

and I execute it. for the second time I want to add another query which is:

```
ALTER TABLE PERSON ADD MATRICULE VARCHAR(50) AFTER CODE;
```

So the file to be executed line's will be :

```
ALTER TABLE adbproject DROP COLUMN imageFormat;
ALTER TABLE PERSON ADD MATRICULE VARCHAR(50) AFTER CODE;
```

but I have logically this error : Can't DROP 'imageFormat'; check that column/key exists. I am searching a way to avoid this error.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` should be a very rare command to use.  Why are you doing so many that you bring up this question?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you should not be trying to create an ever-growing set of queries in this manner.

Of course the first step in your example fails on the second run, since the `imageFormat` column has already been dropped.  There is nothing to restore `imageFormat`and there is no error handling to cope with the missing column.

I cannot fathom why you would want to build up your queries in such a manner.

If your goal is to record every query that you run, then *insert the code into a table that records the time and the code* that you run.

But do not expect to run all the commands without errors unless you have scripted the code to also deal with each exception that may arise.

Comment: I don't know Toad; can you highlight each statement to execute just that statement, the way you can in SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I resort to maintenance scripts like this all the time (in PostgreSQL).

What you can do is using `IF [NOT] EXISTS` where supported (e.g. `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS adbproject_old`), and conditionals otherwise. MySQL doesn't support `IF [NOT] EXISTS` for `ALTER TABLE DROP column`, so you can resort to a conditional.

In your specific example, your script could be:

```
drop procedure if exists schema_change;

delimiter ';;'
create procedure schema_change() begin

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'adbproject' AND column_name = 'imageFormat') THEN
  ALTER TABLE adbproject DROP COLUMN imageFormat;
END IF;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'person' AND column_name = 'matricule') THEN
  ALTER TABLE PERSON ADD MATRICULE VARCHAR(50) AFTER CODE;
END IF;

end;;

delimiter ';'
call schema_change();

drop procedure if exists schema_change;
```

***NOTE***: MySQL Workbench may not allow running the whole script at once. Run until `end;;` first, then run the rest.